# Orchard cms Extending Menu Item part

Tags: orchardcms

What's the best way to extent the Menu part in orchard ?

I want to use the normal menu part for most content types.

But I also want a Custom MainNavigationMenuPart. that has all the things the menu part has but adds a media picker field and a text field to it. - These items that will display on menu rollover.

**Option 1**

I think this is the best way to go ...

I've looked at writing a custom Menu part - but it seem like a lot of functionality for how the menu part currently work is there, I'm not sure how best to tap into this in a DRY way.

I can add a MenuPartItem to my customPart, so main menu part model would look like this

```
public class MainMenuPart : ContentPart<MainMenuRecord>
    {
        public MenuPart MenuPart { get; set; }

        public string ShortDescription
        {
            get { return Record.ShortDescription; }
            set { Record.ShortDescription = value; }
        }

    }
```

But ...

- how do I render this on in the editor view for the part ?
- I want to use the exiting MenuPartItemEditor.
- how do I save this information in the record for the part?

**Option 2**

I've looked also at adding fields to the menu part (via cms).

My menu part now looks like this on the back end

[image]

Here I have customise the admin view for the menu depending on the content type. 
Buy creating a **Parts.Navigation.Menu.Edit.cshtml** in **Views/EditorTemplates**, in my custom them I have access to the menu part, but I can seem to control the display of the fileds I have added to the part. (menu image, highlight, and short description)

Here is the custom Parts.Navigation.Menu.Edit.cshtml (original found in Orchard.Core/Navigation/Views/EditorTemplates/Parts.Navigation.Menu.Edit.cshtml)

```
@model Orchard.Core.Navigation.ViewModels.MenuPartViewModel

@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Core.Navigation.Models;

@if (!Model.ContentItem.TypeDefinition.Settings.ContainsKey("Stereotype") || Model.ContentItem.TypeDefinition.Settings["Stereotype"] != "MenuItem")
{

    if (Model.ContentItem.ContentType == "StandardIndexPage" ||
        Model.ContentItem.ContentType == "AlternateIndexPage" ||
        Model.ContentItem.ContentType == "MapIndexPage")
    {

        var sd = ((dynamic)Model.ContentItem).MenuPart.ShortDescription;

        @sd

        <fieldset>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OnMenu, true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentMenuId, Model.CurrentMenuId)
            <div>
                <label for="MenuText">@T("Menu text (will appear on main menu)")</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MenuText, new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
                <span class="hint">@T("The text that should appear in the menu.")</span>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    }

    else
    {
          <fieldset>

            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.OnMenu)
            <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.OnMenu)" class="forcheckbox">@T("Show on menu")</label>
            <div data-controllerid="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.OnMenu)" class="">
                <select id="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.CurrentMenuId)" name="@Html.FieldNameFor(m => m.CurrentMenuId)">
                    @foreach (ContentItem menu in Model.Menus)
                    {
                        @Html.SelectOption(Model.CurrentMenuId, menu.Id, Html.ItemDisplayText(menu).ToString())
                    }
                </select>
                <span class="hint">@T("Select which menu you want the content item to be displayed on.")</span>

                <label for="MenuText">@T("Menu text")</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MenuText, new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
                <span class="hint">@T("The text that should appear in the menu.")</span>

            </div>
        </fieldset>    
    }


}
else
{

    <fieldset>
        <label for="MenuText">@T("Menu text")</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MenuText, new { @class = "textMedium", autofocus = "autofocus" })
        <span class="hint">@T("The text that should appear in the menu.")</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OnMenu, true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentMenuId, Request["menuId"])
    </fieldset>

}
```

I've also tried to control the display of fields using the placement.info in the theme

```
<Match ContentType="StandardIndexPage">
    <Place Fields_Boolean_Edit-Highlight="-"/>
  </Match>
```

with no success.

Comment: The question is not clear at all. For instance, what is this template named and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Question edited, Hopefully now much more clear

Comment: The theme's placement info won't work in the admin, because your theme is not active when in the admin, except if it's an admin theme (which it isn't). Placement for the admin can be modified from the admin. Go to the content type editor and edit your menu item content type. There is a button there that allows you to change placement.